# One Time Private Key Practical Implementation

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, private-key, pki

First of all I have read [this](http://middleware.internet2.edu/pki07/proceedings/03-guan-otpk.pdf) article which totally describes the OTPK with its advantages and drawbacks. My question is, I believe this method is viable for implementing and I searched the web for any practical implementation. But I did not find any. Do you know any real implementation of this method? Do you know why this method has not been considered so much yet?

Comment: OTPK technology has been [patented in 2005](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2006009517A1?cl=en) and when you take a look at websites of its authors (dsssasia.com and datasecurity3.com) you will know that it has most likely not been successful. From technical point of view the private key is stored in client's host memory so it is protected exactly the same way as traditional software based CSP keys.

Comment: Ok, from technical point of view as you said it is the same as CSP. But just consider that many banking applications are using simple OTP. From security point of view OTPK is as vulnerable as OTP I think and it also enables authentication in transactions. So, I think it is a viable solution for enhancing simple OTP, isn't it?.@jariq

Comment: When you have OTP solution already set up and you need transaction authentication you can almost always use OTP value as a key (shared secret known only to client and server) for [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) function. This way you gain message authetication with no extra cost.

Comment: Interesting! I did not know about that. Thank you for your comment. @jariq

Comment: The link is dead now. Since you know what it was, could you check if it's available at different address and update? Maybe also replace "this" with a title so if later it disappears again, at least there would be a way to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This concept implements solely organizational measures (not technical requirements or alike) and thus it can be implemented using existing PKI solutions. The core is the idea of a very short-live (say 5 minutes) certificate which is discarded by the client after use.

Due to the above there's no need for any "practical implementations". You can use existing PKI libraries to do what they describe.

Comment: Do you know any service supports OTPK?

Comment: @AJeneral No, I am not aware of such. This concept has a weak link - authentication with the CA. And it is harder to secure than in case of long-term certificates. So I doubt that the scheme would ever become widespread.

Comment: Thank you for your brief answer